# Insert multidimensional array in excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to insert data in **Excel**. As an datasource I have a multidimensional array:
Say, I have this

```
dim myArray(5, 3)
for row = 0 to 4
    for col = 0 to 2
        myArray(row, col) = row * col
    next
next
```

How can I insert these array in excel at cell index [0, 0]

### Result

```
  A B C
1 0 0 0
2 0 1 2
3 0 2 4
4 0 3 6
5 0 4 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel arrays (including cell indexes) are 1-based, not 0-based like VBScript arrays, i.e. there is no cell index `[0, 0]`. However, since the offset is constant, it can be handled by simply adding 1 to the index of the VBScript array:

```vb
for row = 0 to UBound(myArray, 1)
    for col = 0 to UBound(myArray, 2)
        xl.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Cells(row+1, col+1) = myArray(row, col)
    next
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for lazies:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a(4, 2) ' Ubounds
Dim r, c
For r = 0 To UBound(a, 1)
    For c = 0 To UBound(a, 2)
        a(r, c) = r * c
    Next
Next

Dim oXls : Set oXls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oWb  : Set oWb  = oXls.Workbooks.Add
oXls.Visible = True
oWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C5") = a
oXls.Quit
```

Evidence:

[image: HowItLooks]

**In case of problems:**

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213798) (you'll have to search for more up-to-date info yourself) -

```
Range("a1:a10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)
```

adding more noise (.Value, .Transpose) may be necessary for all other versions of Excel except mine).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Dim myArray(5, 3)
For Row = 0 To 4
    For col = 0 To 2
        myArray(Row, col) = Row * col
    Next
Next
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1")
For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
    For j = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 2)
        rng.Offset(i, j) = myArray(i, j)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```